# can't show JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm having small problem (I guess) of showing the JTable panel.
I have class contains Object array with:

```
public class Item 

{

  String itemDesc = "";
  float price = 0;
  private itemType enmItemType;
  Object[][] data = {{itemDesc, enmItemType , new Float(price)}};
  .
  .
  .
  .

}
```

here is the Table class contains the JTable:

```
class Table extends JFrame
{
  // Instance attributes used in this example
  private   JPanel      topPanel;
  private   JTable      table;
  private   JScrollPane scrollPane;
  private JButton       update_Button;

  // Constructor of main frame
  public Table()
  {
    // Set the frame characteristics
    setTitle("Add new item" );
    setSize(300, 200);
    setBackground( Color.gray );

    // Create a panel to hold all other components
    topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    getContentPane().add( topPanel );

    // Create columns names
    String columnNames[] = {"Item Description", "Item Type", "Item Price"};

    // Create some data
    Object dataValues[][] ;
    Item itm = new Item();
    dataValues = itm.data;

    // Create a new table instance
    table = new JTable( dataValues, columnNames );

    ////////////////////////////

    JComboBox itemTypeCombobox = new JComboBox();
        TableColumn column1 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    column1.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(itemTypeCombobox));

    ////////////////////////////    

    // Add the table to a scrolling pane
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
    topPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    JButton button = new JButton("Add Item");
    topPanel.add( button, BorderLayout.SOUTH ); 

  }

}
```

The main program is:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    Menu m = new Menu();
    m.chooseMenu();

    // Create an instance of the test application
    Table mainFrame = new Table();
    mainFrame.setVisible( true );   
}
```

I did not receive any error/warning, but still, I don't see any table.
Can someone direct me what causing the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: @Edan: Please try to improve the formatting of your code. Use `Code Sample (Ctrl+K)` instead of `Blockquote (Ctrl+q)`.

Comment: I want it this time as I have compilation errors.. You can still edit your code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cant tell what has gone wrong. But I changed your code a bit (since it had compile time errors)

It works fine for me. Following is the screenshot

[image: Item]

```
public class Item{
    String itemDesc = "";
    float price = 0;
    Object[][] data = {{"test","test","test"},
            {"test","test","test"},
            {"test","test","test"},
            {"test","test","test"}};
}
```

Your main table class

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Menu;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class Table extends JFrame

{
    // Instance attributes used in this example

    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JButton update_Button;

    // Constructor of main frame
    public Table() {
        // Set the frame characteristics
        setTitle("Add new item");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setBackground(Color.gray);

        // Create a panel to hold all other components
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(topPanel);

        // Create columns names
        String columnNames[] = { "Item Description", "Item Type", "Item Price" };

        // Create some data
        Object dataValues[][];
        Item itm = new Item();
        dataValues = itm.data;

        // Create a new table instance
        table = new JTable(dataValues, columnNames);

        // //////////////////////////

        JComboBox itemTypeCombobox = new JComboBox();
        TableColumn column1 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        column1.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(itemTypeCombobox));

        // //////////////////////////

        // Add the table to a scrolling pane
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        topPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton button = new JButton("Add Item");
        topPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Menu m = new Menu();
        // Create an instance of the test application
        Table mainFrame = new Table();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: If I show only the table (Init) so everything alright.. but the problem starts whenever I set value for each parameter of Object.
You might have an idea how to solve this problem? (I want to show the table with parameter that being set during the program itself - for example if I enter new item, then I need to enter parameters of Description (String), type (Enum) and price (Float)...
thanks

Answer (score 2):

> for example if I enter new item, then
>   I need to enter parameters of
>   Description (String), type (Enum) and
>   price (Float)...

To add a new row of data you need to use the addRow(...) method of the DefaultTableModel.

All updates should be done to the model, not the Array used to create the model.